# jquery tooltip not trigger even the element has tooltip plugin associated with it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have an issue with jquery tooltip. Basically, the issue is: after several updates of the tooltip content, the tooltip is not shown again when I mouse hover the element when the tooltip was initially associated with.

To be more specific:

My tooltip is associated with an element `<div class = "tooltipShow">`

The content of the tooltip is updated every time by using:

```
$('.tooltipShow').tooltip("option", "content", newContent)
```

Every time after this step, I can see the content of tooltip changes by doing

`console.log($('.tooltipShow').tooltip("option"))`.

The return is an object with newContent, position and etc.

However, after several updates, the tooltip simply just not show again when I mouse hover `<div class = "tooltipShow">` although I can see that this element still has tooltip plugin associated with it and even the tooltip content is updated one.  It seems like the tooltip is never triggered again since I cannot see any tooltip element is added when I mouse over `<div class = "tooltipShow">`

My jQuery version is "1.8.0"

I will be much appreciated if anyone can help me out~

Comment: Any fiddle or demo available?  There are missing informations, such as what do you do with newContent?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to make a fiddle, but it is from a huge project, it is not easy to put it into a fiddle. The newContent is the content I get from a ajax response. Fox example, I have a button on my interface, once you click the button, one ajax request will be sent and I will have a newContent once I got the response, which contains some number. Then the tooltip content is updated.

Comment: Well I can't help you very much. Does tooltipShow changes? Do your ajax call replaces it with a new instance? Or maybe there's something OVER the tooltipShow that prevents the mouseover to be triggered on it...

Comment: @Bene Ajax call replaces the content of the old tooltip() rather than create another instance and I can see that tooltipShow changes every time. What would be a possible thing that prevents the mouseover to be triggered? On the .tooltipShow element, I have created a highchart and the highchart also has a tooltip when you mouse over the line. Thanks Bene~

Comment: Well I don't know what to say! Without something to check and actually debug, I can't be of much help... Usually listeners get lost in the 4th dimension when you change the DOM Element that has the listener. Since that is not the case, I can't help you much. You should try to make a version visible online ;)

Comment: @Bene I appreciate your help and it is very helpful though. Do you have any reference regarding to "Usually listeners get lost in the 4th dimension", I think that might be one of the reason that cause this issue although I am not entirely sure.

Comment: When you add a listeners, if you remove the DOM Element, the listeners is STILL SOMEWHERE, but won't be triggered by any other DOM Element, even if the new DOM element has the same classes or ID or whatever. I.E: $('#agna').on('click', function(e) { alert( 'foufounes' ) }); $('#agna').remove(); $('.some-container').append('<a href="#" id="agna"></a>'); -> if you click on the new appended "#agna", if won't trigger the ALERT. The listener still exists (let's just say in the 4th dimension :P), the DOM Object has just been modified, yet no trigger possible. Unless you delegate to the container

Comment: jQuery.live() used to fix this, but you should now use jQuery.on() to delegate. $('.some-container').on('click', '#agna', function() { alert('foufounes') }); $('#agna').remove(); $('.some-container').append('<a href="#" id="agna"></a>'); -> if you click on the new appended "#agna", ALERT will be triggered!